# About the GridView control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a web application, on one page I am inserting records in the database and I want to display the data in a GridView but on a diffrent page. How can I do this?

I know how to display records in a GridView, but I want to know if there are two web pages,
on one page provides the facility to insert the records and U want to display the records in the GridView bit on the second page.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more?  It sounds like this question can be logically reduced to "how can I display database records in a gridview?" and there are tons of tutorials for that.

Comment: i have elaborate my question so please help me now david

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to retain the data being inserted without retrieving it from the database, I think it is better to save the data on the first page and retrieve it from the database on the second page.

You can do this by writing inline SQL or a stored procedure. One simple approach would be to pass the resultset into a DataTable and bind a GridView to that.

That does involve more work -- more code and more trips to the database. However, I think it is very useful when performing INSERTs that **the web page is updated to display what actually got into the database**. Sometimes, this is different from what the user thinks they entered, and they can see the problem immediately.

One question would be **how to identify the data that has just been inserted**. I can think of several ways to do that. One is to query for all records entered today by the person logged in (which is recorded in the CreatedBy and CreatedDate columns of the database tables). Sort the resultset in descending order of CreatedDate, so that the most recent entries appear at the top of the GridView. Another would be by assigning a batch number to the data entry and retrieving only the data in that batch.

If you really want to hang on to the data entry, you could put it into Session on the first page, and then retrieve it from Session for display on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

Following along the lines of what DOK said, it's also a lot easier to validate data entered by your users in your business logic before you submit it to the database.

Secondly, users can change their minds about data on a webpage frequently. The data on the web could be in an partially-finished state or could have typos or errors in it. If someone else saw this data and believed that it needed to be completed, then you could end up with duplicated entries in the database that would then require reconciliation.

Honestly, your best bet is to use the Session object to hold temporary user data. The MSDN entry for the [GridView RowEditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx) event contains some great source code for this approach. Whenever I have to use GridViews to handle data from the database, I mimic this.

In addition to handling problems with temporary data storage, you can compare the Session object to your database results to determine whether or not new rows have been inserted. This is somewhat costly as it involves overloading the Equals method (and GetHashCode as well, if you follow what Microsoft recommends) and using Equals to iterate over the two collections, comparing the properties of both objects, and determining which records are new based on records that don't exist in your Session object, but do exist in your database object.

It's also worth noting that this approach assumes that you don't delete data from your database, but set the status of a record in your database to "Deleted" -- if that's a boolean field or an sequence of codes you use to describe the state of rows in a table.